# Dearth of material in Taharas HaBayis on calculating Vesstos

Tags: jewish-books, niddah, hacham-ovadia-yosef, maseches-niddah

The *sefer* Taharas HaBayis is R' Ovadia Yosef's comprehensive compendium on *hilchos Niddah*.  It is 3 volumes, with a lot to say about everything, as one would expect from R' Ovadia.

However, there is a *serious* dearth of material regarding the calculation of *vestos*.  The index in the back has no entries for *maseches Niddah* 62a - 64b (the primary location of these topics), and a mere 4 or 5 entries for Yoreh De'ah Siman 189, the primary *siman* in Shulchan Aruch discussing this topic.

Is there any reason that R' Ovadia has such a lack of content on these topics?  Does he discuss anywhere why he would direct less attention to it?

(For comparison, Badei HaShulchan has 356 *se'ifim* and 382 *tziyunim*, aside from his more in-depth *biurim*, on Siman 189.)

Comment: Probably because it isn't so relevant?

Comment: @DoubleAA He spends pages and pages on רואה מחמת תשמיש, which countless Rabbonim have testified virtually never happens.  And he spent two pages on _vestos_, which has a _nafka mina_ for every single time a married woman has a period.  Was that a joke?

Comment: Roah Machmat Tashmish, be it extremely rare, is EXTREMELY high risk. Like on the level of Aguna. It is incredibly important to elaborate on every possible kula in that field. Vestot Kevuot, while perhaps not that rare, aren't nearly as big a deal. Vestot are probably Derabanan after all. And the real unusual situations are even rarer and resolve themselves quickly.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am still not sure if you are pulling my leg.  He wrote a 3 volume work on every detail of _hilchos Niddah_ and he just skipped _vestos_ because it's "probably Derabanan"?!?!? He didn't take that approach with _kesamim_, I'll tell you that much.

Comment: @DoubleAA And note my question did not mention _vestos kavuos_ - he doesn't talk about _any_ vestos.

Comment: I see 81 pages on Vestot in Volume 1, Siman 2 (pp 40-121). Did you overlook that, or is that too superficial?

Comment: @DoubleAA Before I respond, can you please tell me if "or is that too superficial" was a sarcastic quip or you have a legitimate reason to suspect that I may have considered it superficial?

Comment: Not sarcastic. It doesn't AFAICT discuss much about Vestot Kevuot or Vestot haGuf/Kefitza etc. I found it right away in the table of contents, but you perhaps missed it expecting it at the end instead of the beginning? I don't want to post an answer and be told that you knew that and wanted something more.

Comment: @DoubleAA My question was really a product of a failure to locate virtually anything from siman 189, which was the topics that I referenced in the question. I don't have טהרת הבית at home, so I can't look up what that section is about, but I am going to assume it is about פרישה בעונת הוסת and siman 184, not about calculating _vestos_, be they _vest kavua_ or _eina kavua_.

Comment: @DoubleAA I looked it up today. It is indeed about _perisha b'onas havesses_. However, I did find discussions about the onah beinonis of the chavas da'as (which interestingly enough R' Ovadia seems to assume the shach is the same as) and the ohr zarua (so I'll eat my words from a now deleted comment), which mitigates my wonderment, although it doesn't remove it.

Comment: @DoubleAA I edited the question to reflect this focus.

Comment: According to an anonymous rabbi quoted in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38712/14850), "Rav Ovadia wrote about vestot for his sefer Taharat HaBayit ... but the chapters were lost before they could be published, and Rav Ovadia never rewrote them."

Answer (score 1):

I am not well aquatinted with this compendium, but I beheld that in the start of chapter three which is entitled "Laws of Checkings", he quickly outlines the paradigm of a period.

This is the concluding sentence of the paragraph:

> ויש עוד סוגי וסתות שונים ויתבארו בסימן אחר
>
> There are other period paradigms which will be discussed in a later chapter.

The printers in the 2018 edition added the following footnote:

> כך עלתה במחשבה לפני רבינו, ולא זכינו לאורו
>
> This was our teacher's idea, but we never merited to it's illumination.

The author himself restates this in the commentary on this paragraph:

> עיין בטור שולחן ערוך (ריש סימן קפט). ויתבאר עוד בעזה"י

This may corroborate Joel K's insights.