# Newlyweds: Only four days before Hefsek Tahara?

Tags: women, marriage, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, niddah

I recently saw on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hefsek_taharah#Newlywed) something I had never heard before: that for newlyweds, "a bride counts only four days before performing a hefsek tahara, instead of the usual five." No citation was provided and I am not sure what this means, or it if is true.

- Is this true? What is the source?
- What defines a "newlywed" couple? Is it for the first year of marriage, the first cycle, or...?
- Does it have anything to do with whether the woman is a betulah at marriage?

Related: [Minimum Number of Days before Hefsek Tahara: Sephardi vs. Ashkenazi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31368/minimum-number-of-days-before-hefsek-tahara-sephardi-vs-ashkenazi)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This opinion is cited in the Taz YD 193 sk 4 and 196 sk 5. The idea is roughly that for hymenal bleeding, which only effects a Niddah Derabanan, there is no need to be stringent to add a 5th day. After any ordinary menstrual bleeding, this wouldn't apply. "Marriage" technically has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Seemingly, this logic would apply _a fortiori_ to Dam Tohar.