# Dam Betulah (hymen bleeding)

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot

I heard some one had told me, Dam Betulah need to be wait 3days and,after 7days of cleaning. Is there any poskim that says dam betulah can be wait 3 days so far???

Thankyou

Comment: Are you sure you heard three and not four? Also, what are you assuming is the necessary time to wait for a regular niddah?

Comment: I heard three. It's 4 days for aregular niddah according to rav ovadiah.

Comment: Haven't heard three before. Shulchan Aruch says four https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.193.1?lang=bi

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69721/759

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yadiel and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!